# Batchfile: Problems to get errorlevel, it is always 0

Tags: batch-file, cmd, errorlevel

scripters,
at first sorry for the last post.

Realy, i hope i could make you understand my problem now.

I realized that the problem is inside my script only.

If i run the line in the command prompt it works fine.
That means the Errorlevel is stored to exitCode.txt correctly.

```
START /B "some title" cmd /C "subroutine.bat& >"exitCode.txt" (call echo %^errorlevel%)& >"status.txt" (echo done) & (if defined return call echo %^return%) >"return.txt"" 1>"stdOut.txt" 2>"stdErr.txt"
```

This is a part of my script
So in :treath.run  is the START /B .... line
Inside the script the errorlevel is not stored correctly inside the definded file.

Why?
The return Value is stored perfect.

I dont't get it.

Save this as main.bat

```
        @echo off
        setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION ENABLEEXTENSIONS
        pushd "%~dp0"


        :main
        call :treath.import
        call :treath.init "t1" "call subroutine.bat"
        call :treath.run "t1"
        :loop
        call :treath.status "t1"
        if "!return!"=="done" goto done
        echo !return!
        goto loop
        :done
        echo Now goto "!%t1%.stdExitCode!"
        echo.
        echo The Subroutine should return Errorlevel 1
        echo But it is 0, in the file.
        pause
        EXIT
        goto main
        :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::



        :treath.import ()
        set "return="
        setlocal
        set "objID=__OBJ_TREATH"

        set "workdir=%tmp%\BATCH_OBJ\%objID%"
        if not exist "%workdir%" (mkdir "%workdir%" || exit /b 1)

        set /a "timeout=999"
        :newSessionID
            set /a "sessionID=%random%"
            set "sessionDir=%workdir%\%sessionID%"
            if exist "%sessionDir%" (
                set /a "timeout-=1"
                if !timeout! LSS 0 exit /b 1
                goto newSessionID
            )
        mkdir "%sessionDir%" || exit /b 1

        endlocal & (
            rem set "%objID%_identifier=%objID%"
            set "%objID%_version=0"
            set "%objID%_sessionID=%sessionID%"
            set "%objID%_sessionDir=%sessionDir%"
        )
        exit /b 0
            

        :treath.init (treathName,"command")
        set "return="
        setlocal
        rem hardcoded obj ident
        set "objID=__OBJ_TREATH"
        rem objID

        set "prefix=%objID%_%~1"
        rem treath folder
        set "workdir=!%objID%_sessionDir!\%~1"
        mkdir "%workdir%" || exit /b 1

        set "command=%~2"

        endlocal & (
            
            set "%prefix%.command=%command%"
            set "%prefix%.workdir=%workdir%"
            set "%prefix%.stdOut=%workdir%\stdOut.txt"
            set "%prefix%.stdErr=%workdir%\stdErr.txt"
            set "%prefix%.stdDump=%workdir%\stdDump.txt"
            set "%prefix%.stdExitCode=%workdir%\stdExitCode.txt"
            set "%prefix%.return=%workdir%\return.txt"
            set "%prefix%.stdStatus=%workdir%\stdStatus.txt"
            set "%~1=%prefix%"
        )
        exit /b 0

        :treath.run (treathName)
        set "return="
        setlocal
        set "title=%~1"
        set "prefix=!%~1!"


        type NUL >"!%prefix%.stdExitCode!"
        type NUL >"!%prefix%.stdOut!"
        type NUL >"!%prefix%.stdErr!"
        type NUL >"!%prefix%.stdStatus!"


        rem errorlevel ist immer 0 ???
        START /B "%title%" cmd /C "!%prefix%.command!& >"!%prefix%.stdExitCode!" (call echo %%^errorlevel%%)& >"!%prefix%.stdStatus!" (echo done) & (if defined return call echo %%^return%%) >"!%prefix%.return!"" 1>"!%prefix%.stdOut!" 2>"!%prefix%.stdErr!"

        >"!%prefix%.stdStatus!" (echo running)
        exit /b 0



        :treath.status (treathName)
        set "return="
        setlocal
        set "prefix=!%~1!"
        endlocal & (
            set /p "return="<"!%prefix%.stdStatus!" || exit /b 1
        )
        exit /b 0
```

Save this as "subroutine.bat"

```
set "return=This is a Test"
exit /b 1
```

Comment: It is very difficult for us to determine what exactly you're trying to achieve, because none of your variables are defined or explained in the code, and we cannot put things into context, without your explanation of what you expect at each output. My best current guess would therefore be this single line: ```@Start "%title%" /B %SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /V /Q /D /C "(!%prefix%.command!& (Echo !ErrorLevel!) 1>"!%prefix%.stdExitCode!" & (Echo done) 1>"!%prefix%.stdStatus!" & If Defined return (Echo !return!) 1>"!%prefix%.return!") 1>"!%prefix%.stdOut!" 2>"!%prefix%.stdErr!""```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I also tried the way with "!errorlevel!" it is not working.

Comment: You've submitted completely different code again! and have not explained exactly what you're trying to do. Also your above comment means absolutely nothing to me, because it seems to have no relevance to my previously commented code. I expected you to replace your submitted command line with my code and provide appropriate feedback in relation to your reported problem. It is imperative that you submit a [mcve], along side every piece of information we require to replicate the same issue. Your current submission does not fulfill those parameters.

Comment: In general, when you pass an argument containing doublequotes to `cmd`, the opening and closing doublequotes are removed, and what is enclose between them is received as the intended command(s) to run in that `cmd` instance. So take a look at your current submissions, remove the first and last doublequote, and note that neither example is a command you wish to run.

Comment: `start` – in contrast to the subsequent remark – does not wait until the process is done, unless you add `/WAIT` to it…

Comment: I knew we'd get to the real code in the end... Now given that you are running `subroutine.bat`, could you please tell us what you want `!%prefix%.stdExitCode!`, `!%prefix%.stdStatus!`, `!%prefix%.return!`, `!%prefix%.stdOut!`, and `!%prefix%.stdErr!` to contain? Just to clarify, tell us what the actual content is, and if not as expected, what it should be. There's no use in us fixing one of the outputs, if it changes one or more of the others.

Comment: the subroutine ends with the exit /b 1, means a "1" should be redirected to the !%prefix%.stdExitCode! FILE . But the file contains everytime 0. If i execute the same line of code in the cmd direktly, it works. I thought it is a problem with deleayed expansion etc. but the subroutine defines a "return" var, and the return value is redirected perfect to the file "!%prefix%.return!"